# Replace first word keeping file alignment

Tags: sed, string, replace

I am trying to write a Shell script to edit an input file. Data is structured in the input file as follow:

```
1000␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣: final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

The alignment is made with whitespaces as emphasized in the first line.
I am currently using `sed` to replace the parameters (first "word" of each line).

I couldn't find a way to do it without messing the alignment of the labels. I'm open to any suggestions, I don't particularly want to achieve this with `sed`. It is possible to change the structure of the input file by using tabs for example.

Here's an example of what I would like the script to do:

```
input file
----------
1000␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣: final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

```
running the script
------------------
$ script --final-time=100
```

```
input file after running the script
-----------------------------------
100␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣: final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

The length of the replacement string is not know in advance. It's not fixed and can be up to 6 characters.

Comment: Are the records fixed? You use ‘—final-time’ but the file had a record with ‘final time’ - space instead of hyphen

Comment: No, nothing is fixed @Dani_l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` instead and format the field to the right width with `sprintf()`.  This would most likely be more straight forward than doing it with `sed`.

```
$ cat file
1000            : final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

```
$ awk -F ':' -v sect=' final time' -v val='100' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $2 == sect { $1 = sprintf("%-16s", val) }; 1' file
100             : final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

This treats the input lines consisting of `:`-delimited fields.  When the second field corresponds to the string given to the `sect` variable on the `awk` command line, the first field is replaced by the value given to `val` on the command line.

The way `sprintf()` is used here, with a format string of `%-16s`, ensures that you get a left-justified value that is exactly 16 characters long (padded to the right with spaces), before the `:`.

Setting the "time step" using the same command just requires plugging in other values for `sect` and `val`:

```
$ awk -F ':' -v sect=' time step' -v val='0.12121212' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $2 == sect { $1 = sprintf("%-16s", val) }; 1' file
1000            : final time
1000            : print time
0.12121212      : time step
```

The space at the start of the `sect` value is needed to account for the space in the data after the `:`.  You could also do

```
$ awk -F ':' -v sect='time step' -v val='0.12121212' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $2 == " " sect { $1 = sprintf("%-16s", val) }; 1' file
1000            : final time
1000            : print time
0.12121212      : time step
```

(I moved the space from the `sect` value into the test against the second column's value.)

---

Suggestion for script (using a static file path for the input file and which just *outputs* the modified data):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

filepath=some/file/path

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo expecting two arguments >&2
    exit 1
fi

case $1 in
    --final-time) sect='final time' ;;
    --print-time) sect='print time' ;;
    --time-step)  sect='time step'  ;;
    *)
        printf 'Unknown argument: %s\n' "$1" >&2
        exit 1
esac

val=$2

awk -F ':' -v sect="$sect" -v val="$val" '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    $2 == " " sect { $1 = sprintf("%-16s", val) }; 1' "$filepath"
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer!

Comment: I try to reproduce your script for another purpose and I was wondering what the trailing 1 is here for?

Comment: @Dave The trailing `1` can be replaced by `{ print }` which means it prints each and every line, whether modified or not.

Answer (score 1):

A little `sed` magic

```
v=100; l=${#v}; sed -E "/final/s/[0-9.]/ /g; s/^[ ]{"$l"}/"$v"/" file
```

Since we are looking for `final` we make this a precondition to our match and then obliterate all the numeric and decimals `[0-9.]` with

```
sed -E "/final/s/[0-9.]/ /g;
```

Compose the second half of the `sed` to replace the first `{$l}` spaces with `$v` where `$l` is simply the length of `$v`

```
s/^[ ]{"$l"}/"$v"/"
```

Job done.

Comment: I like the `sed` magic, I'll upvote when I have the power to...

Comment: @dave .... with great power comes great responsibility ;)  ....use it well

Comment: and I got great enough power to .... up-vote. ;-)

Comment: Now I do have the power, up-vote!